# How can I use CodeBlocks with the most recent versions of the VC++ compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, compilation, codeblocks

I need to use C::B with a recent version of MS VC++ compiler like the ones in VS2015 or VS2017, and eventually future ones, but C::B does not offer such option. The most recent VC++ version that C::B allows the user to choose from its list, in the Settings, is VC++2010 (MSVC++10.0) which is quite old. After some search I didn't find an explanation to overcome the problem. Not even C::B site offers a solution. How can I do that?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/arnholm/cpde_utils/blob/master/doc/toolchain/CodeBlocks_MSVC_setup.pdf) is also helpful.

Answer (score 6):

After some attempts I made with C::B settings and VC++ compilers, I found a solution that is not complicate at all. In this post I will show how to use the latest versions of VC++ compiler (MSVC++ 14.0 or higher) with CodeBlocks - with no need to install Visual Studio. The solution would be identical if you prefer to use Visual Studio instead.
I will answer the question for 32 and 64 bits projects. By default it will support std C++14. 
Content: 
A) Install the latest version and compile for x86 projects; 
B) Change to C::B 64bits projects.

A) Install and use for 32bits projects

1. Install the latest version of VC++ compiler.
   The VC++ Toolset can be obtained through NuGet. 
   To get NuGet look here: [NuGet](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).
   Run the following command from the command line. The command installs the latest version is (according [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/16/try-out-the-latest-c-compiler-toolset-without-waiting-for-the-next-update-of-visual-studio/)):
   `c:\\> nuget install VisualCppTools.Community.Daily.VS2017Layout -Version 14.14.26423-Pre -Source https://visualcpp.myget.org/F/dailymsvc/api/v3/index.json`
2. Install  Microsoft Build Tools 2015 (or higher). Here I will stick with 2015, but you can go for 2017.
   For 2015 the installer is here [BuildTools2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159). Run it to install the tools.
3. Open C::B and configure it. C::B last version for Microsoft Visual C++ is 2010. We can use it, but seting a more recent compiler.

   3.1 Go to Settings>>Compiler

   3.2 In "Selected Compiler" select MS visual C++ 2010. This is the higher version available in C::B.

   3.3 Select the Tab "Toolchain executables" and set the Compiler's directory with the directory with the VC++ Toolset. In my case:
   `D:\VisualCppTools.14.0.25114-Pre\lib\native`
   Confirm if the "Program Files" boxes of the tab are filled.

   3.3 Select "Search directories" tab. 
   3.3.1 In "Compiler" tab add the include directory path. 
   In my case is:
   `D:\VisualCppTools.14.0.25114-Pre\lib\native\include`

   Possibly the following will also be needed (from Build Tools).
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt`
   Also if not already there and if needed (in my case)
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um`

   3.3.2 In "Linker" tab enter the paths for the libs. In my case.
   `D:\VisualCppTools.14.0.25114-Pre\lib\native\lib`
   Possibly, also,
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86`
   And if your project complains about uuid.lib, then insert also (in my case),
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86`

   3.3.3 "Resource compiler" tab. This is optional. In my case,
   `D:\VisualCppTools.14.0.25114-Pre\lib\native\include`

And that's it! But if we prefer, C::B allow us to change the compiler name.

B) Change the C::B project settings for x64 projects

1. Point linker libraries' paths to their x64 counterparts. In the Settings menu choose "Search Directories">>"Linker".

   1.1 For the compiler library, add "amd64". In my case:
   `D:\VisualCppTools.14.0.25114-Pre\lib\native\lib\amd64`

   1.2 For "ucrt" and "um" add "\x64" to the paths. Example for my case:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64`
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64`
2. For the compiler select the Tab "Toolchain executables" and insert the prefix "amd64\" for C++ compiler and Make program, as: amd64\cl.exe, amd64\nmake.exe

Again, that's it!

Good work!

Answer (score 1):

Below are compiler options entries for MSVC 2015 installation on Windows 7 when compiling a "plain" C++ console application (no CLI) for a x86 target machine:

```
INCLUDE=
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt

LIB [x86]=
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Lib\um\x86

LIBPATH=
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
```

I added `INCLUDE` and `LIB` to search directories for compiler and linker, respectively, and everything worked in C::B for a x86 console application.
I didn't experiment with x64 architecture...

Comment: In your list the LIB [x86] are paths.
Where exactly did you add them?

Comment: @Sergio
(1) Go to Settings>>Compiler. (2) Select the entry for MSVC 2015. (3) Select "Search directories" tab. (4) In "Linker" tab add all the library paths (listed under LIB [x86]).